# Data is getting pasted twice (base64image and text) from excel to CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor4.x

When I am trying to copy and paste the data from excel to ckeditor it is getting pasted twice as plain text and base64image. I need to paste it as base64image only. Screen shot is attached for reference.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem using following solution

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    extraPlugins : 'pastebase64'
});
editor.on( 'pluginsLoaded', function( event ){
    var excelRegex = RegExp( '(schemas-microsoft-com\:office\:excel)', 'ig' );

    // How to change image, dropped from local folder into CKEditor, from image file to base64 string with the help of CKEditor objects.
    editor.on( 'paste', function( evt ) {
        var testHtml = evt.data.dataTransfer.getData( 'text/html' , true);

        if ( testHtml.search( excelRegex ) >= 0 )
      evt.cancel();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste duplicates images. I did the following:

I changed the file pastebase64 -> plugin.js..
I changed the following snippet:

### line 34:

```
     return Array.prototype.forEach.call(clipboardData.types, function (type, i) {
         if (found) {
             return;
         }

         if (type.match(imageType) ){ // || clipboardData.items[i].type.match(imageType)) {
             readImageAsBase64(clipboardData.items[i], editor);
             return found = true;
         }
     });
```

---

it worked for me....